# Additive Blending with white Background

Tags: opengl, glsl, rendering, transparent

I searched a while, but couldn't find a answer to my problem.

I am trying to add a transparent object in front of an image containing white. For this I use additive transparency

```
//enable trancparency
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
// disable backface culling
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
// disable depth buffer writing
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
// additive blending
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

it looks like this know. 
[White background still white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJoo3.png)[image]

I tried to add

```
glClampColor(GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR, GL_FALSE);
```

Is there a way to say opengl that when he adds red to white it should take the red one and not white?

Sorry my bad english, but I hope someone understands my problem and can help me!

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to say opengl that when he adds red to white it should take the red one and not white?

Of course not; that's impossible. Well, for non-HDR rendering.

Your (non-HDR) colors are clamped to the range [0, 1]. And white is defined a 1.0 for all three channels. The result of your addition will still be clamped to [0, 1]. So 1 + something will still be 1. And 1 + 0 will still be 1.

You cannot make a color channel whiter-than-white.

You probably want linear interpolation blending, not additive:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Additive blending can only be used sparingly in non-HDR rendering systems.

Comment: I tried this, but know there is no sphere at all, just my background image! Did I missed something?

Comment: @mausi: What part of "you cannot make a color channel whiter-than-white" did you not understand? Adding a color to white still leaves it white.

Comment: That's not the point. I tried liniear interpolation, which sounds better than additive. But with this there is no sphere at all. For my opinion it should be the same solution as before, white = white and where i have black in the background i get my red sphere. Or am I wrong?